# Compile time vs Runtime method binding

Tags: java

I am confused by something I am reading in my Pearson Java study book.

I read in my book that the declared type determines the method bind during compiling. During runtime (JVM) the Actual type determines that.
"Which method is invoked is determined by the actual type".
And: "The JVM decides which method is invoked during runtime".

I far as I can tell, runtime is what I am seeing when I run the program.

Suppose I declare:
Object A = new Student();

(The Declared type = object, Actual type = Student)

Now please read the below question/answer in the picture.
I feel the takeaway of the answer, contrasts with the above: It seems as it the Declared Type (ergo: compile time) determines the method match.

Can anyone here maybe shine a light on this?
I feel it is important enough to want to understand this fully!

[image]

Comment: The tl;dr is: the static type(s) of the parameter(s) determine(s) which method is called (in the first case, [`Object`'s `equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is called; in the second case `A`'s `equals(A)` is called, see [JLS, §15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2v)for details).

Comment: There are two equals methods, and they actually have different signatures:

public boolean equals(A a) {...}
public boolean equals(Object other) {...}

The second one comes from the Object class itself, it's built into the JVM.
While the first one is declared in the class A.

The "determined by the actual type" choice is only for exactly the same methods.
In other words if you declared equals in your A class to accept Object (and do instanceof probably?), it would be indeed determined at runtime.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that Turing85 and Piotr both seem right. Empirically proven. It seems that the static type determines the binding. And if I overrride  equals(Object) in class A, the JVM it chooses thát implementation, instead of the Object's default equals(Object). The latter might be the 'runtime' part of the deal. It seems the book that is not really clear on this issue; i was given another impression. Thanks guys!